# What's difference between append_before_action and before_action in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for example：
In controller file，what's difference between
    `append_before_action :calculate, only: :show`
and `before_action :calculate, only: :show` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None. `append_before_action` is the same of `before_action`. [Here's the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a74041d483041345454e766c506dab1b567dec0d/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L219-L220).

`append_` exists for consistency with `prepend_`. For `{before,after,around}` callbacks you have

- `{when}_action`
- `append_{when}_action`, `prepend_{when}_action`
- `skip_{when}_action`

Generally, you should use `before_action`, unless you really need to append/prepend specifically.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, `before_action` will be executed in the order in which it's defined. If you extend a controller, any new `before_action`s will happen after the parent controller's `before_action` methods are executed. If you don't want this to happen, `prepend_before_action` will be necessary to throw your method on top of the stack.